# trigger insert different row

Tags: sqlite, triggers, android-sqlite

The sqlite3 trigger that I want to create might or might not be possible with sql. Five tables are involved:

```
Members               Groups                  GroupMembers      Accounts       
mId |name| accId      gId | name | accId      gId | mId         accId | balance

Orders
oId | accId | ammount
```

When someone deletes a group, I want to make an order for each of the group members with the average of the group balance. So it should do something like this:

```
CREATE NEW TRIGGER triggername 
BEFORE DELETE ON Groups
WHEN ((SELECT balance FROM Accounts WHERE accId=OLD.accId) = 0)
FOR EACH ROW IN 
(SELECT accId 
FROM GroupMembers JOIN Members ON GroupMembers.mId = Members.mId 
WHERE GroupMembers.gId = OLD.gId)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Orders(accId,ammount) VALUES(accId, 
(SELECT balance FROM Accounts WHERE accId = OLD.accId)
 / 
(SELECT SUM(mId) FROM GroupMembers WHERE gId = OLD.gId)
);
END
```

The question is: is it possible to create a FOR EACH ROW in any other table than the table at which the trigger applies? Is it possible to put the WHEN statement before the FOR EACH statement?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: #COUNT(mId) not SUM(mId)

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), there is no such a thing as a `FOR EACH ROW IN ...` clause.

However, the `INSERT` statement [can use a `SELECT` statement as the source of the data to be inserted](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).
Write a `SELECT` statement that returns one row for each group member:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername
AFTER DELETE ON Groups
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Orders(accId, amount)
    SELECT accId,
           (SELECT balance
            FROM Accounts
            WHERE accId = OLD.accId) /
           (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM GroupMembers
            WHERE gId = OLD.gId)
    FROM Members
    WHERE mId IN (SELECT mId
                  FROM GroupMembers
                  WHERE gId = OLD.gId);
END;
```

(I dropped the `balance = 0` filter.)